# How can I create a factory function template that constructs object given an arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: c++

This is easier to explain with some code so I'll give an example first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
    int integer;

    Base() : integer(0) {}
    Base(int i) : integer(i) {}
};

class Double: public Base {
public:
    Double(int i) { integer = i * 2; }
};

class Triple: public Base {
public:
    Triple(int i) { integer = i * 3; }
};

template<typename T>
Base* createBaseObject(int i) {
    return new T(i);
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Base*> objects;

    objects.push_back(createBaseObject<Double>(2));
    objects.push_back(createBaseObject<Triple>(2));

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << objects[i]->integer << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make a function that will return a `Base` pointer to an object that is derived from `Base`.  In the above code the function `createBaseObject` allows me to do that but it restricts me in that it can only create dervied classes that take a single argument into their constructor.

For example if I wanted to make a derived class Multiply:

```
class Multiply: public Base {
public:
    Multiply(int i, int amount) { integer = i * amount; }
};
```

`createBaseObject` wouldn't be able to create a `Multiply` object as it's constructor takes two arguments.

I want to ultimately do something like this:

```
struct BaseCreator {
    typedef Base* (*funcPtr)(int);
    BaseCreator(std::string name, funcPtr f) : identifier(name), func(f) {}

    std::string identifier;
    funcPtr func;
};
```

then, for example, when I get input matching `identifier` I can create a new object of whatever derived class associates with that identifier with whatever arguments were input too and push it to the container.

---

After reading some of the replies I think something like this would suit my needs to be able to procedurally create an instance of an object? I'm not too wise with templates though so I do not know whether this is legal.

```
struct CreatorBase {
    std::string identifier;
    CreatorBase(std::string name) : identifier(name) {}

    template<typename... Args>
    virtual Base* createObject(Args... as) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Creator: public CreatorBase {
    typedef T type;

    template<typename... Args>
    Base* createObject(Args... as) {
        return new type(as...);
    }
};
```

---

Okay here's another semi-solution I've managed to come up with so far:

```
#include <boost\lambda\bind.hpp>
#include <boost\lambda\construct.hpp>
#include <boost\function.hpp>

using namespace boost::lambda;
boost::function<Base(int)> dbl = bind(constructor<Double>(), _1);
boost::function<Base(int, int)> mult = bind(constructor<Multiply>(), _1, _2);
```

Just this has the same limits as the original in that I can't have a single pointer that will point to both `dbl` and `mult`.

Comment: Why does the factory suddenly need to be polymorphic too?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good at explaining. I need to create something that can create an instance of any derived class of Base except I can't directly use the constructor. So that I can link the creation method with the identifier so whenever the identifier is input I can create an instance of the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++11 [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template#C.2B.2B11) can do this for you.

You already have your new derived class:

```
class Multiply: public Base {
public:
    Multiply(int i, int amount) { integer = i * amount; }
};
```

Then change your factory:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
Base* createBaseObject(Args... as) {
    return new T(as...);
};
```

And, finally, allow the arguments to be deduced:

```
objects.push_back(createBaseObject<Multiply>(3,4));
```

#### [Live demo.](http://www.ideone.com/bXqFY)

---

As others have said, though, it does all seem a little pointless. Presumably your true use case is less contrived.

Comment: That means I can't have a single function pointer. I've added some code in my OP at the bottom. I think it'd be a work around but I don't know whether or not it's legal.

Comment: @Rarge: Wha? Where do function pointers come into it? And BTW _you're_ the OP. :)

Comment: I meant original post, sorry. The last part of my unedited post, just before the horizontal rule, was describing my actual use for this which mentioned function pointers.

Comment: @Rarge: You already couldn't do that. Your `createBaseObject` is a _function template_.

Comment: It compiled for me, having a function pointer to `createBaseObject`

Comment: @Rarge: There is no such function as `createBaseObject`.

Comment: yes, but I could create a function pointer to `createBaseObject<Double>` for instance

Comment: @Rarge: Indeed. But the limitation of having to specify the type is merely extended to needing to specify the argument types too. You can't get around that. I class it as the same limitation, not a further one. I guess that could be subjective.

Answer (score 3):

Why not provide multiple overloads with templated parameters?

```
template<typename TBase, TArg>
Base* createBaseObject(TArg p1) {
    return new TBase(p1);
};

template<typename TBase, TArg1, TArg2>
Base* createBaseObject(TArg p1, TArg2 p2) {
    return new TBase(p1, p2);
};
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit how so? Assuming the OP does have a valid usage for this pattern then it gets the job done.  Variadic templates would be nice but most people I encounter don't have access to them in their production environment yet.

Comment: Well, if he doesn't have support for variadic templates then that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use variadic templates:

```
template <typename R, typename ...Args>
Base * createInstance(Args &&... args)
{
    return new R(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Usage: `objects.push_back(createInstance<Gizmo>(1, true, 'a'));`

It's a bit hard to see why you would want this, though, as you might as well just say:

```
objects.push_back(new Gizmo(1, true, 'a'));
```

Even better would be to declare the vector to carry `std::unique_ptr<Base>` elements.

Comment: It's where rvalue refs and `std::forward` start to come into otherwise "simple" code like this that I begin to lose interest in C++11. :(